# The jump at lvl 2 of Prince of Persia classic

Tags: pc, dos, prince-of-persia

I'm at level 2, and I can't do that jump which takes me to the last screen of the level (it's before getting to the door which takes me to  the next level).

Every time I jump to the other side back, after I press the triggerable floor, the prince falls and dies.

In this specific case, I only have two floor tiles wide to make a run jump with <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>></kbd>, but every time I try, the prince doesn't jump from the edge.

I always get close to use his hands, but he doesn't grab for himself.

How I'm supposed to pass that?

(note where by <kbd>></kbd> I mean the right arrow)

Comment: Carefully walk to the edge with Shift + Right Arrow key and then make your jump (Up Arrow).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This has always caused me problems before I figured out the controls - you have to hold Shift while jumping for the Prince to grab onto ledges. When he grabs on, you just have to pull yourself up by pressing Up.

Also as noted, since there is no room for a run up, you have to carefully get to the edge and then jump from the spot.

EDIT: To clarify - walk slowly to the edge, stop, and simply jump, without any running. During the jump (while you're flying) hold shift and you will grab the ledge.